# Reasonable Price/Value for gear-buffing, consumable items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, pricing

In a homebrew campaign I'm running for my seven players, I was looking to introduce a limited amount of consumable weapon buff items that add elemental damage, not unlike the [Pine Resins](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gold-pine-resin) from the Dark Souls franchise.

Essentially, the effect would be something along the lines of "Applied weapon deals an additional 1d8 (Element) Damage for 10 hits/1 minute".
What I'd like to know is for this ~10th level party, what price would be reasonable for such an item, were they to want to purchase more?

Here's my reasoning: I would assume the price to be in the low-mid hundreds. Based off of *Elemental Weapon*, when cast at 5th level, is a bonus action spell lasting up to 1 hour, granting the weapon an additional 2d4 of elemental damage and a +2 magic weapon modifier. It can only be applied to nonmagical weapons however, requires concentration, and requires a spell slot.
The consumable I had in mind would require an action to apply, deal, say, a base of 1d8 elemental damage, last for, say, either 10 hits or 1 minute (whichever comes first), and does not grant the weapon a +2 modifier on attack and damage rolls. I would, however, be applicable to magical weapons as well, since I see no reason otherwise.

Using [Sane Magical Prices](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?424243-Sane-Magic-Item-Prices), I would presume the price would be similar to the difference in cost between a 5th level spell scroll (Upcasted *Elemental Weapon*) and a 4th (+2 Magic Weapon) to get rid of the +2 modifier, which comes out to around 320gp. This does not take into account the huge difference in potential duration, the lack of required concentration, or the possibility that the spell fizzles when being cast from the scroll.

This is where I've kinda hit a wall: How would these factors impact the price?
 Thanks in advance, and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] to see how things work around here. Unfortunately, I think your question is going to be closed as too opinion-based. RPG.SE concentrates on answers with *objectively* correct answers and discussion questions like this are off-topic. I think you'll have better luck asking this question on a discussion forum. [We have a few suggestions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) if you don't know where to look.

Comment: Does the item have a downside besides the gold cost? Would a player ever not use it all the time?

Comment: Items like these would require difficult ingredients to create if they so chose to, and would be in extremely limited supply at a small handful of vendors.

Comment: You are asking about damage die, price, and duration for this item. I suggest changing the question to focus on just the price, and assume the damage die and duration. That way, it is scoped more narrowly.

Comment: I think this is narrow enough now that anyone familiar with creating their own magic items could weigh in on fair pricing.